# How to split data from one website table into different outputs using Python

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm working on a fun project collecting wave data in New Jersey -- I want to scrape this site every day for the upcoming calendar year and look at trends across the board.

My first step though, is setting up the scrape.  Right now, I'm getting an output that includes what looks like two different tables.  Looking at the site though, it seems they might always be in the same  tags.

Is there a way to split this output? I was thinking of doing two different scripts -- one for the "tide data" and the other for the "wave sizes", but it seems I'm not able to split them. (I'm also super new to this)

Ideally, I could have two different scripts that I'll automatically trigger to different tabs of a Google sheet -- I think I can handle that though once I get there.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


id_list = [
    '/Belmar-Surf-Report/3683',
    '/Manasquan-Surf-Report/386/',
    #     '/Ocean-Grove-Surf-Report/7945/',
    #     '/Asbury-Park-Surf-Report/857/',
    #     '/Avon-Surf-Report/4050/',
    #     '/Bay-Head-Surf-Report/4951/',
    #     '/Belmar-Surf-Report/3683/',
    #     '/Boardwalk-Surf-Report/9183/',
    #     '/Bradley-Beach-Surf-Report/7944/',
    #     '/Casino-Surf-Report/9175/',
    #     '/Deal-Surf-Report/822/',
    #     '/Dog-Park-Surf-Report/9174/',
    #     '/Jenkinsons-Surf-Report/4053/',
    #     '/Long-Branch-Surf-Report/7946/',
    #     '/Long-Branch-Surf-Report/7947/',
    #     '/Manasquan-Surf-Report/386/',
    #     '/Monmouth-Beach-Surf-Report/4055/',
    #     '/Ocean-Grove-Surf-Report/7945/',
    #     '/Point-Pleasant-Surf-Report/7942/',
    #     '/Sea-Girt-Surf-Report/7943/',
    #     '/Spring-Lake-Surf-Report/7941/',
    #     '/The-Cove-Surf-Report/385/',
    #     '/Belmar-Surf-Report/3683/',
    #     '/Avon-Surf-Report/4050/',
    #     '/Deal-Surf-Report/822/',
    #     '/North-Street-Surf-Report/4946/',
    #     '/Margate-Pier-Surf-Report/4054/',
    #     '/Ocean-City-NJ-Surf-Report/391/',
    #     '/7th-St-Surf-Report/7918/',
    #     '/Brigantine-Surf-Report/4747/',
    #     '/Brigantine-Seawall-Surf-Report/4942/',
    #     '/Crystals-Surf-Report/4943/',
    #     '/Longport-32nd-St-Surf-Report/1158/',
    #     '/Margate-Pier-Surf-Report/4054/',
    #     '/North-Street-Surf-Report/4946/',
    #     '/Ocean-City-NJ-Surf-Report/391/',
    #     '/South-Carolina-Ave-Surf-Report/4944/',
    #     '/St-James-Surf-Report/7917/',
    #     '/States-Avenue-Surf-Report/390/',
    #     '/Ventnor-Pier-Surf-Report/4945/',
    #     '/14th-Street-Surf-Report/9055/',
    #     '/18th-St-Surf-Report/9056/',
    #     '/30th-St-Surf-Report/9057/',
    #     '/56th-St-Surf-Report/9059/',
    #     '/Diamond-Beach-Surf-Report/9061/',
    #     '/Strathmere-Surf-Report/7919/',
    #     '/The-Cove-Surf-Report/7921/',
    #     '/14th-Street-Surf-Report/9055/',
    #     '/18th-St-Surf-Report/9056/',
    #     '/30th-St-Surf-Report/9057/',
    #     '/56th-St-Surf-Report/9059/',
    #     '/Avalon-Surf-Report/821/',
    #     '/Diamond-Beach-Surf-Report/9061/',
    #     '/Nuns-Beach-Surf-Report/7948/',
    #     '/Poverty-Beach-Surf-Report/4056/',
    #     '/Sea-Isle-City-Surf-Report/1281/',
    #     '/Stockton-Surf-Report/393/',
    #     '/Stone-Harbor-Surf-Report/7920/',
    #     '/Strathmere-Surf-Report/7919/',
    #     '/The-Cove-Surf-Report/7921/',
    #     '/Wildwood-Surf-Report/392/'
]

headers = {

    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

for x in id_list:

    url = 'https://magicseaweed.com' + x

    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        dfs = pd.read_html(str(soup))
        for df in dfs:
            df['City'] = x
            # df.insert(3, "Source", [x], True)

            print(df)
            if df.shape[0] > 0:
                df.to_csv("njwaves3.csv", mode="a", index=False)
            print('____________')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

This is an example URL:

https://magicseaweed.com/Wildwood-Surf-Report/392/

This is the table data that I want to split -- again, right now I'm receiving both tables in one output; I want one script that pulls all of the wave data, then separately another that pulls the high/low tide data

[image: table data]

Is this possible? Any insight is much appreciated

UPDATE ---

I was actually able to very easily scrape these tables using simple Google Sheets functions.

Examples are on tabs "Wave Data" and "Tide Data".

Looking at it this way changes things a bit -- it seems all I really want to do is scrape the FIRST and SECOND tables from the URL (I think).

This is the ideal data output:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mbst-uaRGHWG5ReoFfIsazx0kpY7kXKIBqsRswy1y1Q/edit#gid=1611362673

Comment: Try out this for scraping html tables. You can then transform it in any way you feel like: https://pypi.org/project/html-table-extractor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Not sure if you still need a solution or if the Google Sheets method is enough for you, but here's my suggested method.]

> I want one script that pulls all of the wave data, then separately another that pulls the high/low tide data

You can separate them out into two different functions:

```py
def getWaveData(mSoup, endPt='UNKNOWN'):
    wRows = []
    for tb in mSoup.select('.table-forecast > tbody'):
        wDay = tb.select_one('tr.tbody-title > th > h6')
        if wDay: wDay = wDay.get_text(' ')

        for tr in tb.select('tr[data-timestamp]'):
            wDets = [endPt, wDay]
            for td in tr.select('td'):
                td_ot = td.get('data-original-title', '').strip() 
                td_t = td.get('title', '').strip().replace('&deg', '°') 
                td_c = td.get('class', [])

                if td_ot and 'row-title' not in td_c: wDet = td_ot
                elif td_t and 'row-title' not in td_c: wDet = td_t
                elif td.select('ul.rating'): 
                    wDet = ''.join([mark*len(
                        td.select(f'ul.rating > li.{liClass}')
                    ) for liClass, mark in zip([
                        'active', 'inactive', 'placeholder'
                    ], ['*', '.', '_'])]) 
                elif 'table-forecast-wind' in td_c and td.select('.text-left'):
                    wDet = td.select_one('.text-left').get_text(' ') 
                else: wDet = td.get_text(' ')

                wDets.append(wDet)
            if len(wDets) < 19: 
                wDets = wDets[:-5] + [None]*(19 - len(wDets)) + wDets[-5:]
            if len(wDets) > 18: 
                wRows.append(tuple([' '.join(
                    w for w in wd.split() if w # minimize whitespace
                ) if type(wd) == str else wd for wd in wDets[:19]]))
    return wRows

def getTidesData(mSoup, endPt='UNKNOWN'):
    tRows = []
    for tb in mSoup.select('.table-forecast > tbody'):
        tDay = tb.select_one('tr.tbody-title > th > h6')
        if tDay: tDay = tDay.get_text(' ') 

        rSel = 'tr[data-filter="tides"]'
        cSel = 'td + td:has(+td.text-right), td.text-right'
        for tr in tb.select(f'{rSel}:has(td:is({cSel}))'):
            tDets = [endPt, tDay] + [td.get_text(' ') for td in tr.select(cSel)]

            if len(tDets) < 14:
                tDets = tDets[:-4] + [None]*(14 - len(tDets)) + tDets[-4:]
            if len(tDets) > 13: 
                tRows.append(tuple([' '.join(
                    w for w in t.split() if w # minimize whitespace
                ) if type(t) == str else t for t in tDets[:14]])) 
    return tRows
```

[`endPt` is for the `City` column.] This is not something you can simply use `pd.read_html` for if you want all the data, since some of it is inside tag attributes - also the tides tables are actually pairs of tables inside the last rows of the waves tables.

---

Now you just have to initialize the csv files [and `id_list` and `headers`]

```py
logFp = 'magicseaweed_scrapeLogs.csv' #<-- set None to just print not save
wavesFp = 'waves.csv' #<-- path to csv with waves data
tidesFp = 'tides.csv' #<-- path to csv with tides data
waveCols = [
    'City', 'Date', 'Time', 'Breaking Wave', # ps/ss = primary/secondary swell
    'Swell Rating', 'ps_height', 'ps_length', 'ps_angle', 'ss1_height', 
    'ss1_length', 'ss1_angle', 'ss2_height', 'ss2_length', 'ss2_angle',
    'Wind Speed', 'Wind Direction', 'Weather', 'Temperature', 'Prob.'
]
tideCols = [
    'City', 'Date', 'High1_time', 'High1_ft', 'Low1_time', 'Low1_ft', 
    'High2_time', 'High2_ft', 'Low2_time', 'Low2_ft', 
    'First Light', 'Sunrise', 'Sunset', 'Last Light'
]

for f, h in [(wavesFp, waveCols), (tidesFp, tideCols)]:
    if not os.path.isfile(f):
        pd.DataFrame([tuple(h)]).to_csv(f, index=False, header=False)

# id_list = [....]
# headers = {....}
root_url, idLen, scrapeLog = 'https://magicseaweed.com', len(id_list), []
```

`logFp`/`scrapeLog` is good for keeping track of which sites it failed to scrape from; `logFp` is also the only csv that will be over-written. `wavesFp` and `tidesFp` will be appended to, so they're initialized with the column headers [unless they already exist], because if you're use `.to_csv` with `mode='a'`, you should also use `header=False` if you don't want the header row repeated for every batch of rows.

---

After initializing, you can go ahead and loop through the links:

```py
for i, x in enumerate(id_list[:5]):
    url = root_url + x
    print('', end=f'\r[{i+1} of {idLen}] scraping {url}')
    try:
        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        reqError = r.raise_for_status()
        if reqError:
            scrapeLog.append({'url': url, 'status': 'error', 'msg': reqError})
            continue
    
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        wList, tList = getWaveData(soup, x), getTidesData(soup, x)

        xMsg, xStatus = [], ('success' if wList and tList else 'missing data')
        for f, l in [(wavesFp, wList), (tidesFp, tList)]:
            pd.DataFrame(l).to_csv(f, mode='a', index=False, header=False)
            xMsg.append(f'added {len(l)} rows to {f}') 

        scrapeLog.append({'url':url, 'status':xStatus, 'msg':', '.join(xMsg)})
    except Exception as e:
        scrapeLog.append({'url': url, 'status': 'error', 'msg': f'{type(e)} - {e}'})

print('\n', pd.DataFrame(scrapeLog).to_csv(logFp, index=False))
```

**Please note that this code is dependent on the tables in the scraped page having the same columns as in `waveCols` and `tideCols`, arranged exactly in that order.**

[Spreadsheet with the CSV outputs I got.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12YGR3mTlcJcgGQ9RQkb_aLXjMiaBGV8_91nnuV9KiJk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: This is amazing, thank you for such a thorough and well-thought out answer